# Resolution Error: If your resolution is below 1024 x 768...........

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

Rebooted my PC today and when it restarted, one of my screens is stuck in 640 x 480 resolution. As far as I know, nothing updated.

The "monitor" I am referring to is a 40" Vizio TV Model number M401i-A3 hooked up via mini display port active adapter to HDMI.

It's as if the PC forgot what it is hooked up to somehow. Before in the Screen Resolution, is showed the model number but now it just says Generic Non-PnP Monitor. I looked for a driver for the Vizo but did not find one yet so in the meantime, I am going to look some more.

It also says If your resolution is below 1024 x 768, some items may not fit on the screen.

I should also add that when I go into the Catalyst Control Center, the screen is listed as fake. Also all the Panel Information is listed as not supported. This didn't used to be the case.

Any help is appreciated.